# SQL query to fetch folder's full path starting from Root from HP QC database

Tags: sql

I want to fetch all folder paths available in test lab starting from root to that particular folder. The paths should consist of folder name as well as folder id.

I have posted a query below which I am currently using and it is returning only the folder names in path format divided by `\` e.g.: `Root\folder1\folder2`

But I need in this format `[Root_0\folder1_19\folder2_32]`

the numbers which I am showing after the `_` those are nothing but the folder ids of that folders.

I am trying to fetch result in the above format.

The sql query I am using:

```
with cycle_folders(cf_item_id, cf_item_name) as (
  select cf_item_id, 
         cast(cf_item_name as varchar(1000)) 
  from cycl_fold 
  where cf_father_id<=0 
  union all 
  select cf.cf_item_id, 
         cast(c.cf_item_name + '\' + cf.cf_item_name as varchar(1000)) 
  from cycl_fold cf 
    join cycle_folders c on cf.cf_father_id=c.cf_item_id
)
select cf_item_name as 'Test Set Path', 
       cf_item_id as 'Test Set ID', 
       cy_cycle as 'Test Set Name' 
from cycle c 
    left join cycle_folders cf on c.cy_folder_id=cf.cf_item_id
```

Comment: I removed the `oracledb` tag, because that query is invalid for Oracle (and invalid standard SQL)

Comment: `+ cf.cf_item_id` doesn't work?

Comment: I tried with that also.. It is throwing error saying "conversion failed when converting the varchar value'